# Internet not working on GNOME

Tags: linux, networking, gnome

I am running all my systems on a windows platform.

I am having a PC with the above mentioned OS (This PC is introduced specifically for a project). On this PC I had given the IP address in the range in which other windows PC are working which is 192.168.1.0

This PC is not connected to the domain

From this PC I am able to ping to the PC in this range and also able to ping to the gateway which is 192.168.1.1. I also tried to ping from other windows PC's to this PC and I could successfully do it

With all the setup I am not able to access the internet from this PC. The browser that I am using is Iceweasel

We are having a Sonicwall NSA240 firewall. I checked my firewall and did not see any issue of blockage.

The IP address of the PC is given as 192.168.1.107;
Gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
nameserver 213.42.20.20 also tried 192.168.1.100 (IP of domainserver)

How can I access the internet from this PC?

Comment: The only OS you mention (apart from linux in th the tags) is windows (in windows platform). Gnome is not an OS but a desktop/windows manager. Have you tried pinging an IP address outside of the gateway? One that you know you can ping from one of the other boxes in the subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to ping to google.com from the windows PC and it was successful where as when I tried to do it from the linux PC it was not pinging I also didn't get any message; the cursor was just blinking then I pressed Ctrl + C to cancel command.

Comment: google.com **is not an IP address** but a domain name. You might have problems with name resolving, therefore use e.g. 173.194.113.176, if that works you know where the problem is name resolving and not routing.

Comment: What's the output of `ping -n -c1 8.8.8.8`? and of `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`? and of `host google.com`?